# btrfs problems Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 - can't mount

Tags: server, filesystem, data-recovery, raid, btrfs

I have had a 5 disk btrfs raid 5 running for couple of months now, it has been behaving perfect. Yesterday I could reach the storage raid.

So I ssh'd in to the machine and:

Started to look at the syslog, so this morning:

```
Sep 14 07:50:07 fileserver kernel: [12762.427074] BTRFS warning (device sdb): 'recovery' is deprecated, use 'usebackuproot' instead
Sep 14 07:50:07 fileserver kernel: [12762.427075] BTRFS info (device sdb): trying to use backup root at mount time
Sep 14 07:50:07 fileserver kernel: [12762.427077] BTRFS info (device sdb): disabling disk space caching
Sep 14 07:50:07 fileserver kernel: [12762.427079] BTRFS info (device sdb): force clearing of disk cache
Sep 14 07:50:07 fileserver kernel: [12762.427080] BTRFS info (device sdb): has skinny extents
Sep 14 07:50:07 fileserver kernel: [12762.427795] BTRFS error (device sdb): devid 4 uuid fe572622-b6f2-4d65-b661-813c78c6ccd4 is missing
Sep 14 07:50:07 fileserver kernel: [12762.427823] BTRFS error (device sdb): failed to read chunk tree: -2
Sep 14 07:50:07 fileserver kernel: [12762.473645] BTRFS error (device sdb): open_ctree failed

btrfs fi show
warning, device 4 is missing
Label: 'storagearray'  uuid: 51df26b3-dd33-8c8d-334e1342ca36
        Total devices 6 FS bytes used 839.18GiB
        devid    1 size 1.82TiB used 158.00GiB path /dev/sdd
        devid    2 size 1.82TiB used 158.00GiB path /dev/sde
        devid    3 size 1.82TiB used 158.00GiB path /dev/sdf
        devid    5 size 1.82TiB used 158.01GiB path /dev/sdg
        devid    6 size 1.82TiB used 59.00GiB path /dev/sdb
        *** Some devices missing
```

1 through 6 - 4 missing yes. But I only have 5 disks... so no idea how it can be missing.

When I try to mount it degraded, no matter what disk I choose:

```
mount -t btrfs -o degraded /dev/sdd /mnt/btrfs/
mount: /mnt/btrfs: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdX, 
missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Googled that and ran on all disks:

```
btrfs rescue zero-log /dev/sdX
```

Same result when trying to mount as before.

When I try to balance it:

```
btrfs balance /dev/sdb
ERROR: not a btrfs filesystem: /dev/sdb
root@fileserver:~# btrfs fi show /dev/sdb
warning, device 4 is missing
Label: 'storagearray'  uuid: 51df26b3-dd33-4dd8-8c8d-334e1342ca36
        Total devices 6 FS bytes used 839.18GiB
        devid    1 size 1.82TiB used 158.00GiB path /dev/sdd
        devid    2 size 1.82TiB used 158.00GiB path /dev/sde
        devid    3 size 1.82TiB used 158.00GiB path /dev/sdf
        devid    5 size 1.82TiB used 158.01GiB path /dev/sdg
        devid    6 size 1.82TiB used 59.00GiB path /dev/sdb
        *** Some devices missing
```

I am running out of ideas... please help me save my data!

Comment: I think I have managed to find the disk that is misbehaving using lshw > hardware.xml, very soon I found that it is disk /dev/sdd that is missing. With that I could search the xml file to find what disk it is.
I will remove it and try to mount the raid degraded.

Comment: Did you manage to restore the RAID? What was the problem? Also note that RAID 5 is not fully stable according to BTRFS devs: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Status#RAID56

Comment: That was 18 months ago, but I can tell you that I gave up on btrfs and wnt with madam with XFS instead, in RAID-6. Been working perfectly the last 18 months. :)

Comment: Mmm, I had my share of problems with mdadm, BTRFS has its idiosyncrasies, but it's very robust when properly set up. In my case it was refusing to assemble the RAID rootfs volume during the boot of a Raspberry Pi 4 (both using UUID, label, partUUID, etc.). But it wasn't entirely its fault, it was mostly a USB discovery problem: adding a bit of delay to the local-premount script in the initramfs, I gave the `btrfs device scan` command the time to see all the partitions needed to build the RAID.